# Is there a way call an alias without separating it from previous characters?

Tags: command-line, bash, alias

Super new to all of this. Trying to do the overthewire wargames to learn and thought it was a bit tedious to log in to each level, and wanted to make some shortcuts. I made an alias that can take the password for the next level and pass it through via sshpass which saves a good bit of typing. But I'm wondering if I can do the same for the connection address.

So far I turned this:

```
sshpass -p `sed -n "$p" banditpw` ssh <username>@bandit.labs.overthewire.org -p 2220
```

into just this:

```
sshp <username>@bandit.labs.overthewire.org -p 2200
```

I was wondering if I could do the same for the bandit.labs.overthewire.org -0 2200 part.
I tried doing

```
alias otw="bandit.labs.overthewire.org -p 2220"
```

Which the terminal can recognize until I try to do this:

```
<username>@otw
```

It doesn't recognize I want to call the alias "otw" because it's unbroken from the @. Is there a way to get the terminal to understand I want to call an alias when it's not broken apart from the previous characters?

Also, I would just include the username@ in the alias, except that the username changes each level.

Comment: For the specific case of ssh commands, an entry in your `~/.ssh/config` file will be much more expressive than anything you can achieve with an alias

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to login with something like that

```bsh
$ user1@otw
$ user2@otw
$ user3@otw
```

I purpose to use `function` to login with something easy like that:

```bsh
$ otw user1
$ otw user2
$ otw user3
```

- to make this function, you can do:

```
otw(){
user="$1"
sshpass -p `sed -n "$p" banditpw` ssh ${user}@bandit.labs.overthewire.org -p 2220
}
```